# Oracle version of the IND-PRG game with q queries

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

Consider the following oracle-based game:

> $O_0$:  Init: $1^n$; Query: output $y \stackrel{u}{\in} \{0,1\}^{l(n)}$
>
> $O_1$:  Init: $1^n$; Query: output $G(x)$ with $x \stackrel{u}{\in} \{0,1\}^{n}$

Alice and Bob toss a coin $b \stackrel{u}{\in} \{0,1\}$ and send a black box $O = O_b$ to Eve. Now, consider Eve can do $q$ queries to $O$.

Analyze the advantage of the following distinguisher $D$ which is allowed to query the oracle $q$ times:

> Init: $L = \emptyset$
>
> Repeat:
>
> query $O$ to obtain $y$;
>
> if $y \in L$ output 1; else if $|L| > q$, output $0$;
>
> else $L = L \cup \{y\}$ and continue

**My try**

$P[Win] = \frac 1 2 (P[Win|b = 0]+P[Win|b = 1])$

$P[Win|b = 0] = 1 \cdot \frac{2^{l(n)}-1}{2^{l(n)}} \cdot \frac{2^{l(n)}-2}{2^{l(n)}} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{2^{l(n)}-(q-1)}{2^{l(n)}}= \frac{(2^{l(n)}-1)!}{2^{l(n)}(2^{l(n)}-q)!} \le \Big( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{l(n)}} \Big)^{q-1} $

$P[Win|b = 1] \ge P[\text{collision in the input}] \le \binom{q}{2} \frac{1}{2^{l(n)}}$

**My solution**

For future readers I leave my own solution, I am happy if someone can copy it/improve it, etc and post it as an answer. I will then delete the hand-written version:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think there should be a non negligible advantage for the distinguisher?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your intuition should be wrong. A standard hybrid argument should show that it remains secure. (Although you lose some security in a concrete analysis.)

Comment: I assume that Eve never queries the same value twice - if she does, we can simply ignore the re-query. When $b=1$, Eve wins if she queries $x$ and $x'$ such that $G(x) = G(x')$ and $x \neq x'$. You cannot get an explicit expression for that: e.g. if $G$ was the all-zero function, it would happen with probability one. Hence, you can only upper-bound the probability of the event by a probability that depends on the distinguishing advantage of Eve against the PRG. And I agree with Maeher, if the PRG is secure, the advantage stay negligible after $q$ queries.